# L'hopital rule and anti-derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let the limit: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L \in\mathbb{R}$$

Now, I've been told here that **since the limit exists**, and by L'hopital's rule, we may claim that:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L $$

I've learned that L'hopital's rule can be applied only for $\frac{0}{0}, \frac{\infty}{\infty}$ cases, so I want to understand how can one claim this claim above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

L'hopital's rule applies only for limits involving indeterminate forms, as you have noted. The reason that, $$\lim_{x\to\\c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} $$

must exist, is that without this condition,  $f'$ or $g'$ may exhibit "undampened oscillations" as $x$ approaches $c$. What this means, is that there are certain cases where the expression does not approach a limit as $x$ approaches $c$ because it oscillates as it approaches $c$ instead of arriving at a clearly defined limit.

For instance, consider when the case when $f(x) = \sin(x) + x$, $g(x) = x $, and $c = \infty$. Then, according to l'hopital,

$$\lim_{x\to\\c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \lim_{x\to\\c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1 + cos(x)}{1}$$

This expression clearly does not approach a limit as $x$ approaches $\infty$ since cosine oscillates between 1 and -1. However, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ does exist and can be found to equal 1.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation yet I still don't understand when exactly I can claim (and cannot) that $$\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L \implies \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$$

Comment: I think you have it backwards. The way I learned it, you start with $\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ , then you can use l'hoptital's rule to deduce $L$ from $ \lim_{x\to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$, which implies that $ \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$

Comment: So, you find the derivative of $f$ and $g$. Then if the  $ \lim_{x\to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ has a limit, then it is the  case that the limit of the original is equal to this value. If  $ \lim_{x\to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ does not have a limit, then you cannot use this method to evaluate the limit of the original.

Comment: @nicole No, I believe that the OP has it the right way around. Your last comment is a rewording of the statement.

Comment: Consider how you knew that $ \lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ was of an indeterminate form. Since it was of an indeterminate form, you try different methods. Among them, is l'hopital's rule. You can keep applying l'hopital's rule (if the resulting $f'$ and $g'$ form an indeterminate form) until you either find a limit, or you find that it does not have a limit (I believe when $g'$ is 1, someone correct me if I am wrong) in which case l'hopital's rule cannot be applied.